# how to run chef resource as certain user

Tags: ruby, windows, chef-infra

I'm having issues with installing ruby on to a server with chef without breaking chef commands.

My current idea is to add a user account to run my app and have that user's PATH store the ruby I'm installing separately from chef; that way when I start the app as the new user it won't break chef so easily.

How do I get chef to install and run commands as a particular user?

Either that or can someone point me to the correct way to do this (install and use ruby without breaking chef's internal ruby)

I'm using windows, and yes I know, exercise in sadomasochism and what but this is what I have to do.

Comment: Just as a note - on Linux you can do the following: `chef-client -u user -g group -o cookbook::recipe` but this "change privilege" method is unavailable on Windows. Please correct me if I am wrong someone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most resources that execute a command take a `user` argument:

```
execute 'msiexec /q mumblesomething' do
  user 'me'
end
```